# How to get to JSON array with Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have this Json:

```
{
"version": "firstVersion",
"numberID": "3",
"totalIDs": [
    {
        "1": {
            "subTot": "2",
            "subTotID": {
                "1": "aaa",
                "2": "bbb"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "subTot": "2",
            "subTotID": {
                "1": "www",
                "2": "rrr"
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know how to get the value of version, numberID, but when I try to drill down to get totalIDs > 1 > subTot > value, I don't know how to do it.

Here the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.version);
        console.log(data.numberID);
        console.log(data.totalIDs); // problem is here, I don't know how to drill down further
    }
});
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.
John

Comment: data.totalIDs[0] , data.totalIDs[1]

Comment: totalIDs is an array. You have to use the array index to access entries.

Comment: I have already tried to use data.totalIDs[0] or data.totalIDs[1] and drill down with data.totalIDs[0].subTot, but it gives UNDEFINED each time ...... if I use data.totalIDs[0], it shows me 1 and 2 as following : view from the console.log  [Object { 1={...}, 2={...}}]

Comment: @Jonathan You have two levels of indirection to go through.  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

totalIDs is an array with only one element, a structure.

The structure has two elements indexed by "1" and "2".

You therefore have to include references for both the array and the structure.

```
data.totalIDs[0]["1"].subTot
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get a specific `ID` then try

```
 data.totalIDs[0].subTot or data.totalIDs[1].subTotID[0]
```

Or you can loop

```
 for(var i=0;i<data.totalIDs.length;i++)
 {
    console.log(data.totalIDs[i].subTot); 
    //another loop for subTotID
    for(var j=0;j<data.totalIDs[i].subTotID.length;j++)
    {
        console.log(data.totalIDs[i].subTotID[j]); 
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: "GET",
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.version);
    console.log(data.numberID);

    var length = data.totalIDs.length;
    for(i=0;i<length ;i++)
    {
      console.log(data.totalIDs[i]);
    }
});
```